# Jquery ui sortable limit max to 1 item

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a Main list .sortable and 3 or more other lists connected that I want a person to drag an item and drop which works great and its easy. But i want to be able to limit the new list to 1 item, and they can also drag that item back if they changed their mind and drag a new one.

example what i have so far:
http://jsfiddle.net/TQqdF/25/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the receive option, run some logic and then call 'cancel' on the ui.sender utility object:

```
$('#main_list,ul').sortable({
        placeholder: 'placeholder',
        connectWith: '.connect_lists',
        receive: function(event, ui) {
            var $this = $(this);
            if ($this.children('li').length > 1 && $this.attr('id') != "main_list") {
                console.log('Only one per list!');
                $(ui.sender).sortable('cancel');
            }
        }
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TQqdF/62/

[Updated as per John's helpful and correct comment!]

[Update: If it's not one thing it's another! Now it seems that there's no way to avoid the animation (`revert: true` that you set). However, I have a *partial* solution for the problem mentioned further in the comment thread.

If you use absolutely positioned LI elements inside a relatively positioned UL, new items being added will not push the others out of the way. However, you do need to explicitly declare that those same LI items are statically positioned when inside the draggables container. Here's the CSS I threw at the bottom of your existing code:

```
#droppables ul { position: relative; }
#droppables li { position: absolute; top: 3px; left: 3px; }
#draggables li { position: static; }
```

And a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w38dK/5/

So, the main thing left is that it animates before being rejected and reverting. I had a poke around the docs and I couldn't find a way to resolve it. Perhaps a second question on Stack Overflow specifically regarding that issue?

Comment: Quick question what the heck does cancel do? i tried googling about it but no answer. Also the documentation sayings not much about it.

Comment: It's a method specific to the jQuery UI framework and its Sortable interaction. All it does is revert the elements back to the state they were in before the sort started. It works by passing the 'ui' object into the receive parameter's function, meaning you then have access to the sender within (ui.sender). The interaction's .sortable() method happens to have an option called 'cancel' which does the reverting I mentioned. Not sure if that answers your question. ;-)

Comment: @Greg Pettit, doh you got here first while I was trying to figure it out.. I had left off the `function(event, ui)` part so wasn't getting the ui to fire. You'll want to make sure to ignore the `main_list` though so you can move items back to it.

Comment: Ironically, I was taking my time rather than rushing to an answer like so many people do (grr), but I still missed that main_list logic that you correctly identify as necessary to the whole thing. Good catch! Upped your answer 'coz that logic is a requirement!

Comment: Hey its fun trying to answer questions here, I learned how to do this trying to answer the question :), +1 to you :)

Comment: Ok so i implemented ur demo to what im trying to build 
http://jsfiddle.net/w38dK/1/ which works great but when i drag a new box , it will temporary hide whats already there because its trying to sort , how can i stop that ? functionally it works amazing! but i wanna also make visually correct.

Comment: Instead of the receive event, you could tap into one of the other events that might be earlier in the chain. You should still be able to use the "canceling ui.sender" part of it. http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#events

Comment: I FAIL SO BAD!! I cant seem to get this to work, if I use over I crash the code.

Comment: Ack, I didn't notice you had provided a fiddle. My advice in the comment isn't helpful. Tapping into events earlier in the chain isn't going to help because it's the hover-over that's clearing out the target. It could end up being CSS rather than JS for a solution but I don't have any sample code.

Comment: No this question is answered, I used #draggables li { position: relative;} instead of static because it didn't revert back from absolute when dragging back to main list. If you throw me ur email i'll paypal you $5 for helping me out =D

Answer (score 6):

If anyone is still interested, I took a slightly different approach to solving this problem.

Instead of using the receive event, I use mousedown and mouseup events on the list items to detect whether the target lists are at their max or not.

This essentially disables the target lists upon click if they are already full. This means no nasty placeholder.

```
$('.sortable li').mousedown(function() {
    $('.sortable').not($(this).parent()).each(function() {
        if ($(this).find('li').length >= 1) {
            if ($(this).attr('id') != "main_list" ) {
                $(this).sortable('disable');
            }
        }
    });
});
$('.sortable li').mouseup(function() {
    $('.sortable').each(function() {
        $(this).sortable('enable');
    });
});
```

Full jsfiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/P9bS8/

Answer (score 2):

Here is my version: http://jsfiddle.net/DwXnV/3

Dragged item replaces content of target list. Replaced item is moved to origin list.
Assumed that each target list can contain only 1 item.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use the receive event and make sure to ignore the `main_list` so you can put items back.

```
 $('#main_list,ul').sortable({
        placeholder:'placeholder',
        connectWith: '.connect_lists',
        receive: function(event, ui) {
            var list = $(this);
            if (list.attr('id') != "main_list") {
                if (list.children().length > 1) {
                    alert("More than 1!");
                    // move item back to main_list
                    $(ui.sender).sortable('cancel');
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Check the events section on [jqueryui sortable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/)

http://jsfiddle.net/TQqdF/61/